# Android issue with compare 2 Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

i have a two bitmap which have images i want to compare both of these but i cant do this . please tell me how to do this/? i have a wifi base app in which user connect to wifi when he set the wallpaper wallpaper save in the sharedprefrences and again get it now when user again connected to this wifi his wallpaper auto change to this which he have save in sharedprefrence.now problem is this its not compare bitmap to check if wallpaper already have same image then it does nothing and if bitmap are not equal then it set the sharedfrefences save image to wallpaper. 
here is my code.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
//
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo mWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

                if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
                        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        final WifiInfo conn = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, con.getSSID()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if (conn.getSSID().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("\"" + homewifi + "\"")) {

                        final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                        final Drawable wal = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
                        final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)wal).getBitmap();

                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                        final byte[][] b = {baos.toByteArray()};
                        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b[0], Base64.DEFAULT);
                        // textEncode.setText(encodedImage);

                        SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit=shre.edit();
                        edit.putString("image_data",encodedImage);
                        edit.commit();

                        final String previouslyEncodedImage = shre.getString("image_data", "");

                                    b[0] = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
                                    bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b[0], 0, b[0].length);

                                        if (!bitmap.equals(bit)) {
                                            try {
                                                context.setWallpaper(bit);
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                            Toast.makeText(Profile1Activity.this,"wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(Profile1Activity.this,"wallpaper already set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }      
                    }
                }
                    else {

                    }

                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        }, 5000);

    }
```

Comment: where u set file for wallpaper?

Comment: if (!bitmap.equals(bit)) {
                                            try {
                                                context.setWallpaper(bit);
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String mergeTwoImg(String botImgPath, String topImgPath, float leftPadding, float topPadding) {
        Bitmap bottomImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(botImgPath);
        Bitmap topImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(topImgPath);

        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bottomImage.getWidth(), bottomImage.getHeight(), conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap

        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(bmp);

        comboImage.drawBitmap(bottomImage, 0f, 0f, null);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(topImage, leftPadding, topPadding, null);

        File file = new File(outPath + "/mergingImg.png");
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }

        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(outPath + "/mergingImg.png");
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, os);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return outPath + "/mergingImg.png";
    }
```

Comment: you can check my code i have no file i get wallpaper from wallpaperManager